# .htaccess rewrite working on 2.4 but not on 2.2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First an explanation of what I am trying to achieve here: If I share a url on google/facebook and so on, I want them to scrape a different page than what users see.

I have the following rewrite rule defined which works on my local machine running Apache 2.4. (I test this by changing my user agent string)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet|Google) [NC]
RewriteRule event/(\d*)$ http://example.com/sharepage.php?id=$1 [P,L]
```

Our public server is running Apache 2.2 though and I keep getting a response of 500 Internal Server Error. Oddly enough no errors are being logged in the apache error logs.

I have also checked that `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are enabled.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have an unescaped space in the _CondPattern_ - although this should have resulted in a 500 error on any version (so I guess this might be a typo?). Why do you need the `P` flag? Is `example.com` a different domain?

Comment: @w3dk Yes the space is an error I made when copying and pasting here. The P flag causes Apache to remap rather than to redirect according to this post: http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app